# How to define relations inside @freezed entity with objectbox dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, objectbox, freezed

By following [this](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/issues/229)

I have a `CurrentUser` entity as follows:

```
import 'package:admin/core/auth/enums/content_type.dart';
import 'package:admin/core/permission/model/permission.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:objectbox/objectbox.dart';

part 'current_user.freezed.dart';
part 'current_user.g.dart';

@freezed
class CurrentUser with _$CurrentUser {
  @Entity(realClass: CurrentUser)
  factory CurrentUser(
      {@Id(assignable: true) int? localId,
      @Unique() String? id,
      required DateTime createdAt,
      required DateTime updatedAt,
      required String email,
      required String username,
      String? mobile,
      @Default(false) bool? isEmailConfirmed,
      @Default(false) bool? isMobileConfirmed,
      @Default(false) bool? isSuperAdmin,
      @Default([]) List<ContentType>? accessTo,
      DateTime? lastLoginAt,
      DateTime? lastLogoutAt,
      @Default([]) List<Permission>? permissions}) = _CurrentUser;

  factory CurrentUser.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$CurrentUserFromJson(json);
}
```

But here the field `permissions` should be a One-to-Many relation with model `Permission`. How to define the relation in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is something like this `@Default(ToMany<Permission>()) List<Permission>? permissions` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would actually use `ToMany` (or `ToOne`) as the parameter type, so

```
required ToMany<Permission> permissions
```

for this example. `ToMany` (or `ToOne`) has a special constructor for this case that accepts a list of items (or a single item for `ToOne`).

See also the freezed test entities from objectbox-dart: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/blob/main/generator/integration-tests/part-partof/lib/frozen.dart

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work.

Comment: But how can I define an enum converter inside the entity denoted by @freezed? Here the `Permission` entity has an `action` enum representing CRUD, but @freezed seems to only support custom getter.

Comment: Think I have to use String for such case, and do some type conversions outside of entity class.